# Android take picture and get path?

Tags: android

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

...

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {  
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photoResultView);  
        image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);  
    }
```

How to get image's path to string?

Answer (score 7):

As it's said in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE):

> The caller may pass an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where this image will be written. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field. This is useful for applications that only need a small image. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is present, then the full-sized image will be written to the Uri value of EXTRA_OUTPUT.

Comment: Yes, this is usefull. But I need the image path to upload the full-size picture. If you have idea - shoot. :)

Comment: The last sentence: If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is present, then the full-sized image will be written to the Uri value of EXTRA_OUTPUT. So, that's for the full-sized pictures.